# Window height too long after ajax loaded content is resized in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have created a responsive one page website that loads in chunks of content via ajax. When the main index page is resized to a smaller width (mobile size) and then adjusted back, the window does not adjust the height back to the original height of the conent and leaves a huge chunck of whitespace underneath and scrollbars that are too long.

Have tried adjusting the window size

```
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
    var bodyHeight = $(body).css(height, '100%');
    $(window).height(bodyHeight); 
    });
 </script>
```

and

```
window.resizeTo(width,height)
```

nothing seems to work, suggestions appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using auto instead of 100% on the body height. And you wont need to set the window height. might want to do something like this if auto does not work: 

$(body).css('height', $(window).height())

Comment: tried both to no avail